# Remove Bar In Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2015

How would I go about removing the bar that says "Restart | (Global Scope) | err(int error, const char * desc)"? I am coding in C, and want to clean up my UI to not have unnecessary elements. I've been able to strip the UI of almost everything, but I don't know what this bar is called, and as a result, don't know where to look to get rid of it.

[image: VS Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the "navigation bar."  Remove it under Tools->Options->Text Editor->C/C++.  There's a checkbox for it.